# Error in using cookie function in Single Page App

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application

I have a Single Page App in Reactjs.

I tired to use below function:

```
cookies.set("user",{
                    id: user.id, token: response.data.token, email: this.state.email
                });
```

When I want to login in my Single Page App I have error like this: `cookie__WEBPACK_MODULE_5___default.a.set is not a function`

On the top of my app I include cookie by `import cookies from 'cookie'`.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module you are using is a [Node js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie) module which has some V8 bindings to it. So, it can't run on browsers. I suggest you use [Js cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie) instead.

In js cookie you can set a cookie in a similar manner - 
`Cookies.set('name', 'value');`